# Replacing Negative values with "0" for raster layer

Tags: raster, qgis-3, calculate-values

I am trying to change negative values (raster layer) into `"0"` but I cannot find a way to do that.

Does anyone know how to accomplish it in QGIS 3.2?

I found an answer somewhere on the Internet to use the Python console entering `'0 if !field! < 0 else !field!'` but I have no experience using Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend **Raster calculator**.

If your raster layername is `RasterA`, then try `(RasterA@1 >= 0) * RasterA@1`

- If the cell value is 0 or greater than 0, `(RasterA@1 >= 0)` returns `1` (i.e. True)
- If the cell value is less than 0, `(RasterA@1 >= 0)` returns `0` (i.e. False).

In short, `(RasterA@1 >= 0)` acts as a Boolean mask.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like the values >0 to remain the original values and the values  <=0 changed into 0.  I used rastercalculator to create a raster where cells represent deviation from optimum pH. For negatives & 0 the pH is okay.

Comment: That's what this calculation does. The equation returns the original cell value when the original cell value is greater than or equal to zero. When the original cell value is less than zero, it returns 0. So all values less than zero are converted to zero, while all other values remain unchanged..

Comment: Thanks @csk ! Please excuse my lack of explanation, ClaKie.